# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whisper' when trying install in sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker, openai-whisper

I'm trying to install openai-whisper on AWS Sagemaker. I've tried creating virtual env, upgrading to python 3.9 and found out the installation get "Killed" before it even finishes. I need help solving this, been struggling for a couple for days. Thanks in advance.

```
pip install openai-whisper
```

Traceback:

```
Keyring is skipped due to an exception: 'keyring.backends'
Collecting openai-whisper
  Using cached openai-whisper-20230306.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting torch
Killed
```

```
import whisper
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_13713/3212043240.py in <module>
----> 1 import whisper

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whisper'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the last line of the installation logs, this is happening because the installation gets killed due to running out of memory.

Use the following for your installation when you encounter the issue:

`pip install openai-whisper --no-cache-dir`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to implement this with no virtual environment and let us know what happens? Are you doing this in Studio or Classic Notebook Instances?